# Unable to see my contacts

Tags: iphone

I am unable to see my contacts since few days. It has been working fine since I changed from iphone 6s to iphone 7. However since last two days I do not see any contacts. Can someone please help me to get this back? I have tried to sync my Gmail and icloud but it does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your contacts groups? If you click the groups button on the top left you can check which contact groups you want to see (such as google or iCloud contacts). You may have accidentally disabled some.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already checked with that. Strange thing is that even gmail contacts are not showing up. Tried to sync icloud and gmail both again.

Comment: Does anything come up in the groups list? Also have you tried on another device?

Comment: Yes I can see both iCloud and gmail checked in the groups. Yes previously I had iPhone 6s and I signed out from that device.

Comment: Yes that is strange. You sure the contacts weren't saved locally?

Comment: Or didn't you say it worked for a while

Comment: Yes it did worked. So when I got my new iPhone 7 and signed into iCloud and Gmail I got all the contacts and I can still see the photos which were backed up on my previous phone on iCloud it's just the contacts which disappears suddenly

Comment: Strange. The only thing I can think of is completely signing out of both iCloud and gmail and signing back in. That may force some special type of first time sync that may work. I would also try checking your google contacts on the web via a computer to verify that they are indeed on the cloud (same goes for iCloud).

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. I will check that out. How about performing a reset on the phone?

Comment: No problem! That may work as well. If the contacts are on the cloud then the phone should be able to get them. A reset definitely could help.